# Galerkin method for nonlinear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dx}u+u^2+x$$
$$x \in \Omega=[0,1]$$
$$BCS:u|_{x=0}=1;\frac{du}{dx}|_{x=1}=1$$

You can see that the right side contains $u^2$. So when I paste it in the weighted residual form, I get nonlinear term.
For example, if I have approximation:

$$ u=1+\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i x^i$$
There will be nonlinear integral in weighted residuals
$$\int (1+\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i x^i)^2dx$$
That's why the system will be nonlinear. What am I missing?

I tried to switch from $u$ to $u^2$ in equation because $u\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{du^2}{dx}$, but can't make it for $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$

**Edit, according to the answer:**

I won't write BCS integrals, because they don't make real sense in the question. I'll write only the integral in the main domain. So I have
$$\int_0^1w(\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\frac{du}{dx}u-u^2-x)dx=0$$
$w-$weight function. Paste approximation of $u$. Let's take $n = 2$
$$\int_0^1w(2\alpha_2-(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 x)(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)-(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)^2-x)dx=0$$
Take in account Bubnov-Galerkin approximation of weight function:
$$ w=\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2$$
$$\int_0^1\beta_1x(2\alpha_2-(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 x)(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)-(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)^2-x)dx +\int_0^1\beta_2x^2(2\alpha_2-(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 x)(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)-(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)^2-x)dx=0$$
From here since $\beta_i $ arbitrary we have system

$$\begin{cases}
 \int_0^1x(2\alpha_2-(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 x)(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)-(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)^2-x)dx =0\\
\int_0^1x^2(2\alpha_2-(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2 x)(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)-(1+\alpha_1 x +\alpha_2 x^2)^2-x)dx=0
\end{cases}
$$

Here we exactly have unknowns only $\alpha_i;i=1,2$.But if we extend polynomial to $2n=4$ we will have new  $\alpha_i;i=1..4$ with 2 equations only

**Edit 2:**

Actually I need two terms approximation, so I don't think that switching to 2n terms and then solving 2n equations is the key point. I suppose we should simplify ode, or choose another interpolation functions rather then $x^i$

Comment: Does $*$ stand for ordinary multiplication or [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)?

Comment: @md2perpe ordinary multiplication

Answer (score 2):

You missed nothing, the product is non-linear. However, you can extend your polynomial expansion with

$$\int (1+\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i x^i)^2dx\equiv\int  (1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\tilde{\alpha_i} x^i) dx.$$

The product of $u\cdot u$ is still a polynomial, however with a higher polynomial degree of $2n$.

The Galerkin solution can be derived by integrating $$\int (1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\tilde{\alpha_i} x^i) dx$$ and considering only the first $n$ coefficients of $\tilde{\alpha_i}$. Simply spoken: Coefficients greater $n$ are neglected.

The truncation of the additional $n$ modes can be  intepreted as projection in a $2n$ dimensional space onto a $n$ dimensional space where the solution is orthogonal to the chosen subspaces.

This is the key property of the Galerkin approach.

Regards

Comment: I think I cannot change approximation, because after this in Galerkin method you make a system, where we find $\alpha$. So when we extended polynomial, we add more $\alpha 's$ but not equations to the system, and we can't find the exact solution of it

Comment: I think you do not get the point entirely. You will get the Galerkin solution if you integrate $$\int (1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\tilde{\alpha_i} x^i) dx.$$ The Galerkin solution are the first $n$ coefficients of $\tilde{\alpha_i}$.

Comment: Actually, I can't understand how to solve this system. Please, look at my edits to the main question

Comment: Why do you think you can't add more equations. This will automatically happen if you directly consider 2n coefficients from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, when I write approximation in 2n coefficients I have 2n equations, but doesn't this follow from your answer, that if I write 2n approximation then the nonlinear part $u^2$ should be $4n$. And, please, can you provide a direct example how $u^2$ can be approximated with $2n$ coefficients for $n=2$.Thanks a lot

Comment: No here is our misunderstanding. The Galerkin solution is simply the integral with 2n coefficient, you do not consider 2n equations. After you have integrated your solution, you simply consider the first n coefficients only.

Answer (score 1):

Considering instead the ODE

$$
u''+u'u+u^2-x=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

with better behavior regarding the polynomial approximation, the Galerkin procedure can be handled as follows.

1 - Choosing a convenient orthogonal basis into the interval as for instance the shifted Tchebicheff polynomials $\theta_k$ in $[0,1]$  we make an approximating sequence as

$$
u_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \theta_k(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

2 - Calculate the residual $r_n(x,a_k)$ from $(1)$ after substitution of $(2)$

3 - Calculate the relationships

$$
g_i(a_k) = \int_0^1 r_n(x, a_k)\theta_i(x) dx, \ \ i = 1,\cdots, n
$$

4 - Calculate the boundary conditions

$$
\cases{b_1(a_k) = u_n(0)-1\\
       b_2(a_k) = u'_n(0)-1}
$$

5 - Solve the minimization problem

$$
\min_{a_k}\sum_{i=0}^n g_i^2(a_k)\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \{b_1(a_k) = 0,  b_2(a_k) = 0\}
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script to illustrate that

```
t[x, 0] = 1;
t[x, 1] = x;
t[x_, k_] := t[x, k] = 2 x t[x, k - 1] - t[x, k - 2]
n = 4;
theta = Table[t[x, k], {k, 0, n}];
thetas = theta /. {x -> 2 y - 1};
u[x_] := Sum[Subscript[a, k]  thetas[[k]], {k, 1, n}]
A = Table[Subscript[a, k], {k, 1, n}]
d[u_, x_] := D[u, x, x] + D[u, x] u + u^2 - x
equs = Table[Integrate[d[u[y], y] thetas[[k]], {y, 0, 1}], {k, 1, n}];
bc1 = (u[y] /. {y -> 0}) - 1
bc2 = (D[u[y], y] /. {y -> 0}) - 1
sol = NMinimize[{equs.equs, bc1 == bc2 == 0}, A]
u0 = u[x] /. sol[[2]];
solux = NDSolve[{d[v[x], x] == 0, v[0] == v'[0] == 1}, v, {x, 0, 1}][[1]];
plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[v[x] /. solux], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = Plot[u0, {y, 0, 1}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

Attached a plot showing in red the solution for $(1)$ and in blue for $n = 4$ the approximation.

[image]

Comment: I think that the questioner is more interested in understanding and knowing how to solve the problem analytically. It is known that the original form is nonlinear and therefore only solvable with a nonlinear equation system solver. What is the contribution here?

Comment: Many times in practice, the theory is another thing.

Comment: As you say, not useful for understanding at all, acceptable for a practitioner.

Comment: The paths of enlightenment are diverse and unsuspected.