# Galerkin method for system of ode's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I have the following system of ode's
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{du_1}{dx}=u_1+u_2,\\
\frac{du_2}{dx}=u_1u_2
\end{cases}
$$
BCS
$$\frac{du_1}{dx}|_{x=0}=1,\frac{du_2}{dx}|_{x=1}=2 $$
$$x \in\Omega=[0,1]$$
I want to solve it with Bubnov-Galerkin method

So my approximation to functions is:
$$u_1(x)=\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2$$
$$u_2(x)=\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2$$
And weight functions are:
$$w_1(x)=\alpha_{11}x+\alpha_{22}x^2$$
$$w_2(x)=\beta_{11}x+\beta_{22}x^2$$
Now I write weighted residual form of equations:

$$\int_0^1w_1(x)(\frac{du_1}{dx}-u_1-u_2)dx +w_1(0)(\frac{du_1}{dx}-1)|_{x=0}=0$$
$$\int_0^1w_2(x)(\frac{du_2}{dx}-u_1u_2)dx +w_2(1)(\frac{du_2}{dx}-2)|_{x=1}=0$$
Now paste my approximation:
$$\int_0^1(\alpha_{11}x+\alpha_{22}x^2)(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2x-\alpha_1x-\alpha_2x^2-\beta_{1}x-\beta_{2}x^2)dx = 0$$
$$\int_0^1(\beta_{11}x+\beta_{22}x^2)(\beta_1+2\beta_2x-u_1u_2)dx + (\beta_{11}+\beta_{22})(\beta_1+2\beta_2-2)=0$$
Since the parameters $\alpha_{11},\alpha_{22},\beta_{11},\beta_{22}$ are arbitrary we get the following four equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\int_0^1x(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2x-\alpha_1x-\alpha_2x^2-\beta_{1}x-\beta_{2}x^2)dx = 0\\
\int_0^1x^2(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2x-\alpha_1x-\alpha_2x^2-\beta_{1}x-\beta_{2}x^2)dx = 0\\
\int_0^1x(\beta_1+2\beta_2x-u_1u_2)dx + (\beta_1+2\beta_2-2)=0\\
\int_0^1x^2(\beta_1+2\beta_2x-u_1u_2)dx + (\beta_1+2\beta_2-2)=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
As you can see in the last two integrals there is a term $u_1u_2$, which. is nonlinear and gives us coeeficients like $\alpha_1\beta_1$. How can I get rid of them, and make system linear? Or maybe I should make another approximations at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The question was already answered in another thread

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740524/galerkin-method-for-nonlinear-ode/3740573#3740573)

with two different solutions:

- Extend your polynomial expansion and apply a projection
- Solve a minimization problem

Regards